# How to Use AutoLayout in storyboard in iOS?

Tags: ios

Can't understand auto-layout help me or suggest me how to learn AutoLayout to application perfect for all screen in iPhone.

Comment: use the autolayout in biginning for learning tutorial or example.

Comment: To learn AutoLayout go thoroughly from given tutorials, which explain basics in details :  1)http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/

2) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html

Comment: What's wrong with typing `auto layout tutorial` in google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Learning, there are many sources.

You can visit [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html) to understand about Auto Layout Constraints.

For quick fix,

1. Select your view controller and set its width and height to any. "w Any h Any" as shown in the number 1 "Auto Layout quick fix image"
2. Add the User Interface Items and then select the view controller and do as shown in the number 2 - "Auto Layout quick fix image"

[Auto Layout quick fix image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OM3YN.png)

Sometimes there will be possibility of failure for adding the constraints by XCode.